# jQuery: How to search the user defined array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The user can define how many `<select>` he will choose and when the `<select>` on change event is triggered, the value of the `<select>` will be push to array. So basically, the value and the length of an array is depending on the user. Now, what I want is if the user already selected that specific value on other `<select>` and he tries to select it on the other `<select>`, it will prompt a message that the item already selected. Well, the item will be the name of the existing value he is about to select. I really don't know how to do it. Here is my codes for adding the `<select>`.

```js
var a = 1;
$('#add').click(function() {
  var cnt = $('#append').val();
  for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    a++;
    $('#contain').append('<select class="sel" name="' + a + '"></select><button id="remove" name="' + a + '">x</button><br name="' + a + '"/>');
  }
  var selval = $('#contain select').val();
  var optarr = [];
  $('#contain #sel1 option').each(function() {
    var opt = $(this).val();
    if (opt != selval && opt != 'null') {
      optarr.push(opt);
    }
  });
  var optjoin = optarr.join(',');
  var optlen = optarr.length;
  var optsplit = optjoin.split(',');
  for (var x = 0; x < optlen; x++) {
    var optappend = '<option value="' + optsplit[x] + '">' + optsplit[x] + '</option>';
    $('#contain select.sel[name="' + a + '"]').append(optappend);
  }
});
$(document).on('click', '#contain #remove', function() {
  $('#contain select.sel, #contain #remove, #contain br').remove('[name="' + a + '"]');
  a--;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='append' value='1' />
<button id='add'>+</button>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id='contain'>
  <select id='sel1' class='sel1'>
    <option value='val1'>val1</option>
    <option value='val2'>val2</option>
    <option value='val3'>val3</option>
    <option value='val4'>val4</option>
    <option value='val1'>val5</option>
    <option value='val2'>val6</option>
    <option value='val3'>val7</option>
    <option value='val4'>val8</option>
    <option value='val3'>val9</option>
    <option value='val4'>val10</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `filter()` method without the need for jQuery.

Run the snippet I created below.

The important piece of code is when `var filtered` gets assigned. I created two tests. See below the comments `// first test` and `// second test`.

You can check if `filtered.length === 0` to see if the target value is in the array as demonstrated in the `inArray()` function.

```js
var array = ['val1', 'val4', 'val2'],
    filtered;

function inArray(outputId) {
    var inArrayText = filtered.length === 0 ? 'NO' : 'YES';
    document.getElementById(outputId).innerHTML = inArrayText;
}

// first test
filtered = array.filter(function (val) {
    return val === 'val5';
});
inArray('result1');

// second test
filtered = array.filter(function (val) {
    return val === 'val2';
});
inArray('result2');
```

```html
<div>Is 'val5' in ['val1', 'val4', 'val2']? <span id="result1"></span></div>
<div>Is 'val2' in ['val1', 'val4', 'val2']? <span id="result2"></span></div>
```

If you need to use jQuery, as user86745458 suggested, you can use jQuery's `inArray()` like so:

`var indexOfValInArray = $.inArray(val, array);`

This gets the index where `val` is located in the `array` or -1 if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think it is good if the array is already fixed, but my array depends on the user. have you run my code above?

Comment: I ran your code, but it's confusing. I'm not sure what it is doing currently. Do you have an example (like on another website) that is completed that you would like for your code to do?

Comment: I have already explained on what i want to do on my code. I want it to prompt something like "[item] already selected" where the item is the name of the existing value. and I want it to happened on change event but i don't know how. I tried the `inArray()` function but the problem is that it always return true since that I loop to all the present `<select>` value and it happens that it also include the `<select>` that the user is currently selecting. here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xnpjpmr9/1/)

Comment: I updated your fiddle. I made a few changes in `$(document).on()`. Based off the new `<select>`'s values, it will alert `"item found"` when you use your original `<select>` to choose an existing value. I think there are other issues outside of that functionality that you have to fix. Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/xnpjpmr9/2/

Comment: I created 3 `<select>` with a value val1, val2,val2 respectively. Why is it that when I change the second `<select>`, it alerts the item found?